# How to make synonyms work with fuzziness in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a synonyms.txt

```
auto, vehicle => car
```

In the settings I have:

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "def_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
        "filter": ["lowercase", "synonym"]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "synonym": {
        "type": "synonym",
        "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the document I have row with the value "car"

Then in the query I apply this analyzer and fuzziness and try to search with a synonym "vehicle" with a small typo:

```
title: {
  query: 'vhicle',
  operator: 'OR',
  fuzziness: 'auto',
  analyzer: 'def_analyzer',
},
```

As a result 0 results. Although if edit the query to use the synonym "vehicle", it will return "car". And if you write something like "crr" it will find "car" - so fuzziness doesn't work for synonyms here for some reason. Only for the original value in index.

Answer (score 0):

The [search_analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) can help you to fix the issue. You can use both `analyzer` and `search_analyzer` in the mapping.

### Here is the logic:

**1. check the query and add fuzziness**

query `vhicle` became `vehicle`

**2. check synonym table**

`vehicle` became `car`

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete", 
        "search_analyzer": "standard" 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. What is the mapping in your answer about? Sorry, didn't get it. I already have fuzziness in the query and mapping for synonyms mentioned in the original question.

Comment: I recommend creating a new index with this mapping (mapping includes both analyzer and search_analyzer) and reindexing your data.